Solution for line break with BR tag after updating Quill to 2.0
After updating the quill to 2.0 previous solution to line break stopped working. I tried to apply and adopt many solutions available here for the previous version with no success.
I got to the point when a line break with the BR tag was applied in editing mode. Unfortunately, when I'm initiating a new quill instance with preloaded data containing BRs, they are all converted to paragraphs and I wasn't able to code a working solution for that.
Could you help me, please?
I'm attaching the working part of my code:
import Quill from 'quill';
import { EmbedBlot } from 'parchment';

class SoftBreak extends EmbedBlot {
  static create(value) {
    let node = super.create(value);
    return node;
  }

  length() {
    return 1;
  }

  value() {
    return '\n';
  }

  static value(node) {
    return '\n';
  }
}

SoftBreak.blotName = 'softbreak';
SoftBreak.tagName = 'BR';

Quill.register(SoftBreak);

export const quillConfig = {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
    keyboard: {
      bindings: {
        linebreak: { 
          key: 'Enter',
          shiftKey: true,
          handler: function(range, context) {
            const quill = this.quill;
            const currentLength = quill.getLength();

            quill.insertEmbed(range.index, 'softbreak', '');
            quill.setSelection(Math.min(range.index + 1, currentLength), Quill.sources.SILENT);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I initiate quill as follows:
quillContainer.innerHTML = htmlData;
quill = new Quill(quillContainer, quillConfig);
quill.focus();

htmlData contains HTML previously saved from quill.
